# Quarkus Keycloak specific docker image

Tags: keycloak, quarkus

Is there a way to specify the Keycloak version which is used in dev/test mode in quarkus ?
The default one on the 2.15.0.Final version is 19.0.3 and I want to use the 20.0.2.

I search in multiple documentations but I didn't find anything.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify which image to use for the keycloak dev service (that is what will be loaded in dev/test mode) using the `quarkus.keycloak.devservices.image-name` property.

Example :

```
quarkus.keycloak.devservices.image-name=quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:20.0.2
```

Note that if the image name does not end with -legacy, Quarkus will assume it is a Keycloak Quarkus image.

You'll find all configuration properties for the Keycloak Dev service here : https://quarkus.io/guides/dev-services#keycloak